# Is it possible to recover from an erroneous eval in hint?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, interpreter, either

I am trying to use `hint` package from `hackage` to create a simple environment where user can issue lines of code for evaluation (like in ghci). I expect some of the input lines to be erroneous (`eval` would end the session with an error). How can I create a robust session that ignores erroneous input (or better: it reports an error but can accept other input) and keeps the previously consistent state?

Also, I would like to use it in `do` style, i.e. `let a = 3` as standalone input line makes sense.

---

To clarify things: I have no problem with a single `eval`. What I would like to do, is allow continuing evaluation even after some step failed. Also I would like to incrementally extend a monadic chain (as you do in `ghci` I guess).

In other words: I want something like this, except that I get to evaluate `3` and don't stop at `undefined` with the error.

```
runInterpreter $ setImports [ "Prelude" ] >> eval "undefined" >> eval "3"
```

More specifically I would like something like this to be possible:

```
runInterpreter $ setImports ... >> eval' "let a = (1, 2)" -- modifying context
                                >> typeOf "b" -- error but not breaking the chain
                                >> typeOf "a" -- (Num a, Num b) => (a, b)
```

I don't expect it to work this straightforwardly, this is just to show the idea. I basically would like to build up some context (as you do in ghci) and every addition to the context would modify it only if there is no failure, failures could be logged or explicitly retrieved after each attempt to modify the context.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show any code so I don't know the problem.  The most straight-forward way I use hint handles errors fine:

```
import Language.Haskell.Interpreter
let doEval s = runInterpreter $ setImports ["Prelude"] >> eval s
```

has resulted in fine output for me...

```
Prelude Language.Haskell.Interpreter> doEval "1 + 2"
Right "3"
Prelude Language.Haskell.Interpreter> doEval "1 + 'c'"
```

```
ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 7.10.2 for x86_64-apple-darwin):
        nameModule doEval_a43r
```

... Except that now the impossible happens... that's a bug.  Notice you are supposed to get `Left someError` in cases like these:

```
data InterpreterError
  = UnknownError String
  | WontCompile [GhcError]
  | NotAllowed String
  | GhcException String
        -- Defined in ‘hint-0.4.2.3:Hint.Base’
```

Have you looked through the ghchq bug list and/or submitted an issue?

EDIT:

And the correct functionality is back, at least as of GHC 7.10.3 x64 on OS X with hint version 0.4.2.3.  In other words, it appears the bug went away from 7.10.2 to 7.10.3

The output is:

> Left (WontCompile [GhcError {errMsg = ":3:3:\n    No instance for (Num Char) arising from a use of \8216+\8217\n    In the expression: 1 + 'c'\n    In an equation for \8216e_11\8217: e_11 = 1 + 'c'\n    In the first argument of \8216show_M439719814875238119360034\8217, namely\n      \8216(let e_11 = 1 + 'c' in e_11)\8217"}])

Though executing the `doEval` line *twice in GHCi does cause a panic*, things seem to work once in the interpreter and properly regardless when compiled.

Comment: I have modified the question, hope it clarifies my intentions.